# Grouping particle pairs into all combinations

Tags: python, combinations

Have a sub-list of list that is:

```
List1 = [(2112, 1270.0, -0.14, -0.174, 1270.0), (2112, 35.0, 0.296, 0.205, 34.9), (2212, 846.0, -0.0431, -0.16, -846.0), (2112, 1.9, 0.128, -0.109, -1.64)]
```

Just need to create all combinations of pairs of particles with ID's 2112 and 2212 so that output looks like this for this paticular sub-list of list:

```
Combination1 = [(2112, 1270.0, -0.14, -0.174, 1270.0), (2212, 846.0, -0.0431, -0.16, -846.0)]
Combination2 = [(2112, 35.0, 0.296, 0.205, 34.9), (2212, 846.0, -0.0431, -0.16, -846.0)] 
Combination3 = [(2112, 1.9, 0.128, -0.109, -1.64), (2112, 35.0, 0.296, 0.205, 34.9)]
```

For some sublists it can have a lot of entries, so need to automate this somehow.
If possible interested in knowing how to do it both ways. i.e. with and without use of a library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following. This code produces all possible pairs with the first id being smaller than the second, to avoid duplicates:

```
import itertools

res=[i for i in itertools.product(List1, List1) if i[0][0]<i[1][0]]

>>>print(res)

[((2112, 1270.0, -0.14, -0.174, 1270.0), (2212, 846.0, -0.0431, -0.16, -846.0)), ((2112, 35.0, 0.296, 0.205, 34.9), (2212, 846.0, -0.0431, -0.16, -846.0)), ((2112, 1.9, 0.128, -0.109, -1.64), (2212, 846.0, -0.0431, -0.16, -846.0))]
```

Answer (score 0):

This code first select all particles with id = 1 or 2 to reduce the amount of data to process. Then, the program creates all combination of particles without duplication.

```py
import itertools


def main():
    data = [(1, 1270.0),
            (1, 35.0),
            (2, 846.0),
            (1, 1.9),
            (3, 2.3)]

    y = filter(lambda x: x[0] in [1, 2], data)
    z = list(list(k) for k in itertools.combinations(y, 2))
    print(z)
    # [[(1, 1270.0), (1, 35.0)], 
    #  [(1, 1270.0), (2, 846.0)], 
    #  [(1, 1270.0), (1, 1.9)], 
    #  [(1, 35.0), (2, 846.0)], 
    #  [(1, 35.0), (1, 1.9)], 
    #  [(2, 846.0), (1, 1.9)]]  


main()
```